# PHP Fatal error: Class 'Aschroder_SMTPPro_Model_Mysql4_Setup' not found

Tags: magento-1.9, fatal-error, compiler

I have a similar problem. My compiler was turned on and I did the installation. Now, getting error 500 and log file shows this error

> [21-Sep-2016 01:25:37 UTC] PHP Fatal error: Class
>   'Aschroder_SMTPPro_Model_Mysql4_Setup' not found in
>   /home/strateg2/public_html/picworks.in/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup.php
>   on line 234

I'm unable to log in to admin panel. How to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1:**

Turn Off the compiler from your terminal steps

1) open your terminal /connect your ssh access

2) go to your magento root via this command `cd \yourpathtomagentoDir`

3) fire this commnad  `php -f compiler.php disable`

4) after this do compile `php -f compiler.php compile`

5) after this enable compile `php -f compiler.php enable`

**Solution 2:**

1) go to your module's xml file located in `app/etc/modules` and disable the module

2) clear the cache

3) now you are able to login in back end

4) disable the compiler and install your module

5) do compile and enable your magento compile

Answer (score 0):

I think Aschroder SMTPPro extension does not posses it's set up file. So create a file like this.

**File:** **`app/code/<codePool>/Aschroder/SMTPPro/Model/Mysql4/Setup.php`**

```
<?php
class Aschroder_SMTPPro_Model_Mysql4_Setup extends Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup
{
}
```

That will resolve this issue.

**Note:** codepool may be local or community depends upon where **`Aschroder_SMTPPro`** module resides.